# Some python packages are not installed with docker but others are

Tags: python, docker

**TL/DR**

I had a horrible puzzle to solve that didn't seem to be tackled anywhere in the web, so now I'm posting it here in case anybody else has the same trouble. Is is already solved, see my answer below.

It was related to pip install, not installing those packages that missed a wheel file.

---

**Long explanation.**

When running `docker-compose up` everything seemed to work like a charm in the building images stage, no errors reported... until the containers where started... then I got some weird errors like this one:

```
@@Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/bin/flask", line 8, in <module>
sys.exit(main())
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/flask/cli.py", line 894, in main
cli.main(args=args, prog_name=name)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/flask/cli.py", line 557, in main
return super(FlaskGroup, self).main(*args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/click/core.py", line 717, in main
rv = self.invoke(ctx)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/click/core.py", line 1132, in invoke
cmd_name, cmd, args = self.resolve_command(ctx, args)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/click/core.py", line 1171, in resolve_command
cmd = self.get_command(ctx, cmd_name)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/flask/cli.py", line 500, in get_command
self._load_plugin_commands()
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/flask/cli.py", line 496, in _load_plugin_commands
self.add_command(ep.load(), ep.name)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/_init_.py", line 2464, in load
self.require(*args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/_init_.py", line 2487, in require
items = working_set.resolve(reqs, env, installer, extras=self.extras)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/_init_.py", line 777, in resolve
raise DistributionNotFound(req, requirers)
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: The 'alembic>=0.6' distribution was not found and is required by the application
```

It seemed that many packages were missing even though I didn't run into any errors when docker was installing them.

And more weird: when entering the container with `docker run --rm -it --entrypoint bash <service-name>` I could manually install all missing packages using `pip3 install -r /var/www/webapp/requirements.txt.lock` with no problem. And all errors would be gone. This is the exact same command that my Dockerfile uses in order to install python packages when building it's image.

We had no clue on:

1. Why this was happening now, since it worked until at least a couple
   of weeks ago for the last 2 years!
2. Why did dockerfile fail but manually running exactly the same command worked.
3. Why only certain packages were missing, and no errors were raised for them.
4. How to fix this.

Answer (score 3):

I started my research, took many hours but to summarize:

1. It seemed that the missing packages didn't have a wheel file in their [pypi](https://pypi.org/) repository. So pip was falling into ["legacy" direct installation](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/8102) but only for those packages, that's why the others were installed properly.
2. I found that many of these missing packages, like [alembic](https://pypi.org/project/alembic/), do have a .whl file but in [later versions](https://pypi.org/project/alembic/#files), not the one we were using: [0.9.9](https://pypi.org/project/alembic/0.9.9/#files).
3. It seems that the package Wheel is needed to build a .whl file for those packages that do not include them in their pypi repository. But doing a `pip list` inside the container showed that wheel was indeed already installed...
4. I tried manually deleting the wheel package, and running `pip3 install -r /var/www/webapp/requirements.txt.lock` again... voilá, the same errors that docker reported. the packages without a wheel file were not installed. So I found out that wheel package:

> has two different roles:
>
> 1- A setuptools extension for building wheels that provides the
> bdist_wheel setuptools command
>
> 2- A command line tool for working with wheel files

From those 2, the first point seemed to be what was missing from happening.

**5. Long story short, in my dockerfile, before installing the requirements, I installed wheel, problem solved.**

---

**But why did this happen now and not before??**

I found that even if docker didn’t install wheel before running the pip install, it did have setuptools. I don’t exactly know how those two packages work, and less I understand how they cowork to get things done. But searching on [setuptools changelog](https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/history.html) I found that it is updated quite frequently, almost daily.

More interesting, version v60.4.0 of 08 Jan 2022 seemed to be pretty big for the standard of the others, and it includes this as one of the changes:

> #2968: Removed tmp_src test fixture. Previously this fixture was copying all the files and folders under the project root, including
> the .git directory, which is error prone and increases testing time.
>
> Since tmp_src was used to populate virtual environments (installing
> the version of setuptools under test via the source tree), it was
> replaced by the new setuptools_sdist and setuptools_wheel fixtures
> (that are build only once per session testing and can be shared
> between all the workers for read-only usage).

Not sure, but maybe it did change sth related to how packages without a wheel file were installed and now it wouldn't work without package Wheel doing it.